# C++11 compilation error while using lambda over map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, lambda

Why the following code doesn't compile:

```
int main() {
  map<int, int> m  = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}};

  auto p = std::min(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const map<int, int>::value_type& a, const map<int, int>::value_type& b)         { return a.second < b.second;});

  std::cout << (p->second) << std::endl;
}
```

The error is:

```
X.cc:11:114: note: main()::<lambda(const value_type&, const value_type&)>
X.cc:11:114: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::pair<const int, int>&}'
```

What am I doing wrong here? If that was over a vector, say vector of ints, we could have done

```
[](int a, int b){return a<b;}
```

Why can't we do the same thing here?

Comment: Please be specific about "not work". Is it not compiling? Then whats your error? Is it running but crashing? Again whats the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) instead of [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min).

Answer (score 1):

`std::min` takes the value types as the first 2 arguments, you're passing *iterators*.

I guess what you're trying to achieve is the element in the map with the smallest `.second`, so min_element is what you need.